# The quotient group of a quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following question.

If we have two subgroups $U$ and $V$ of a given $\textbf{abelian}$ group G does the following hold?

$$\frac{G/V}{U}\cong \frac{G/U}{V}?$$

I wrote out the representatives and I am pretty sure that this statem

Comment: Perhaps I'm just inexperienced, but I don't think that that makes any sense. $G/V$ is a group whose elements are cosets of $G$, $U$ is a subgroup of $V$. You can't factor $G/V$ by $U$ since it's not a subgroup of $G/V$.

Comment: @KevinLong: That was my reaction as well, but if I wanted to interpret $U$ as a subgroup of $G/V$ I think there's basically exactly one sensible way of doing so, namely taking the image of $U$ under the quotient map. Not sure if that's standard notation though...

Answer (score 4):

As written, the question makes no sence. $\frac{G/V}{U}$ is not defined, since $U$ is a subgroup of $G$, not $G/V$.

By the way, you may be interested in the [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem), [third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem) and [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)) isomorphism theorems for groups.